# Защищенное соединение вебсокетов php

Tags: php, websocket, ssl

Доброго времени суток. Я использую библиотеку Workerman для создания вебсокет-сервера. Без защищенного соединения все работает, а вот когда пытаюсь настроить wss, то все слетает. На [странице проекта](https://github.com/walkor/Workerman#enable-ssl) написано, что нужно передать файлы local_cert и local_pk. Как я понимаю, эти файлы создавались при получении ssl-сертификата, который я получал через letsencrypt. Т.е. они должны находиться в папке /etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru. Там у меня есть 4 .pem файла (cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, privkey.pem). Если я верно понимаю, мне нужны cert.pem и privkey.pem (но вот только в примере на гитхабе файл .key, но таких я у себя не нашел). Если я передаю эти файлы, сервер нормально запускается, а когда пытаюсь подключиться через `ws = new WebSocket("wss://site.ru:8000");`, то браузер выдает ошибку `WebSocket connection to 'wss://site.ru:8000/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled`

Часть кода при создании websocket-сервера:

```
$context = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'local_cert' => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/cert.pem',
        'local_pk'   => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/site.ru/privkey.pem'
    )
);

// создаём ws-сервер
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:8000", $context);
$ws_worker->transport = 'ssl';
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я вообще всё это понимаю, те ли файлы подключаю, в чем может быть моя ошибка?

Comment: Была подобная проблема. Решил проксированием трафика в апаче. Т.е. с клиента идёт через wss, а апач переводит в ws

Comment: @ArchDemon, хм, попробую, но я надеялся, что есть более красивый способ.

Comment: Была аналогичная проблема, wss на janus не открывался, wss на ws проксировать вообще не вариант, решение нашли банальное - перешли на другой сертификат, [sslforfree](https://www.sslforfree.com/) подошел, с ним без проблем всё заработало

Comment: скорее всего, у вашего скрипта нет доступа к /etc
можно сделать симлинк куда-то в область видимости /var/www/...

Answer (score 1):

А Вы не пробовали добавить `'verify_peer' => false` в указанный $context? У меня на локальном сервере работает именно при таком варианте:

```
$worker = new Worker('websocket://0.0.0.0:8084', [
    'ssl' => [
        'local_cert'  => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/cert.pem',
        'local_pk'    => '/etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem',
        'verify_peer' => false,
    ]
]);
```

А вот на рабочем сервере такая же проблема, пока не решил. Если в кратце, то Workerman выбрасывает такую ошибку: `Error: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL_R_NO_SHARED_CIPHER: no suitable shared cipher could be used.  This could be because the server is missing an SSL certificate (local_cert context option)`. Самое интересное, что при использовании самозаверенных сертификатов такой проблемы нет!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема, скорее всего, в настройках веб-сервера. Нужен отдельный VirtualHost на порт 8000 с настройками SSL, как для 443. Но я тоже пошёл путём проксирования wss в ws.